# How can i fix this File "<string>" error in python

Tags: python, websphere, jython, wsadmin

I trying to do the simple script and its throwing the below error at for loop,

```
WASX7017E: Exception received while running file "/abc/websphere/wasad/createusers.py"; 
exception information: com.ibm.bsf.BSFException: exception from Jython:
Traceback (innermost last):
File "<string>", line 22, in ?
AttributeError: __getitem__

filename=sys.argv[0]
file_read= open( filename)   ---- this is line 22
for row in file_read:
```

Please let me know the reason for this.

Here you can find my code,

```
  import sys

  filename="/usr/websphere/onefolder/Userlist.txt"
  fileread = open(filename, 'r')
  for row in fileread:
     column=row.strip().split(';')
     user_name=column[0]
     pass_word=column[1]
     AdminTask.createUser(['-uid',user_name, '-password', pass_word, '-confirmPassword',   pass_word])
     AdminTask.mapUsersToAdminRole(['-roleName','Administrator','-userids',user_name])
     AdminTask.addMemberToGroup('[-memberUniqueName user_name,o=defaultWIMFileBasedRealm -groupUniqueName cn=webarch,o=defaultWIMFileBasedRealm]')

  fileread.close()

  AdminConfig.save()

  print 'Saving Configuration is completed'
```

Comment: Please can you post the Python code in your question. You should edit the question rather than reply to the comment. Thanks

Comment: Indentation is important in python, it's how code blocks are defined. Fix your indentation, it's worng.

Comment: I have just modified the indentation of for loop...can you be specific what are all the lines to be modified?

Comment: Can't say. What is `AdminTask`? And which line in *your* code is executed when the error is raised?

Comment: Admin Task Websphere command to create user, am getting the error exactly at " for row in fileread: "

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to iterate over each line in the file.  The `open` method in Python returns a file object.  If you want to iterate over each line in the file, you'll need to call `readlines` to retrieve the contents of the file, and then loop over that.

This should work:

```
import sys

filename="/usr/websphere/onefolder/Userlist.txt"
fileread = open(filename, 'r')

filelines = fileread.readlines()  

for row in filelines:
   column=row.strip().split(';')
   user_name=column[0]
   pass_word=column[1]
   AdminTask.createUser(['-uid',user_name, '-password', pass_word, '-confirmPassword',   pass_word])
   AdminTask.mapUsersToAdminRole(['-roleName','Administrator','-userids',user_name])
   AdminTask.addMemberToGroup('[-memberUniqueName user_name,o=defaultWIMFileBasedRealm -groupUniqueName cn=webarch,o=defaultWIMFileBasedRealm]')

fileread.close()

AdminConfig.save()

print 'Saving Configuration is completed'
```